Did prophet Muhammad know Aramaic/Hebrew or any other languages?
Is there any source or reference or evidence about the languages in which the Prophet Muhammad was fluent?
Specially that Quran is very much inspired by the Old Testament.

As far as I know, the Quran was revealed to prophet Muhammad by Allah through the Archangel Gabriel. If so, no intermediate language would be necessary. Why Muhammad was chosen to be prophet to receive the revelation of the Quran is a very different question, and some may call it even a heretic one.

For the moment I don't see any reason for why Quran is fully original, in the sense that one can argue the Prophet did not know of any other holy text at all. @GyroGearloose

The Quran, by definition, is original. That doesn't contradict the fact that part of it was revealed previously in other religious texts. It is a matter of believe.

What can be proven based on common sense should not be believed. Belief is meaningful if only things are beyond the scope of proof. @GyroGearloose

There is a Hadeeth saying he was fluent in every language (or at least 72 languages), and the Hadeeth I remember was interpreting this verse of Quran that Allah the Almighty has stated

وَ مَا أَرْسَلْنَاكَ إِلَّا كَافَّةً لِلنَّاسِ بَشِيرًا وَ نَذِيرًا وَ لَكِنَّ أَكْثَرَ النَّاسِ لَا يَعْلَمُونَ
We have not sent thee but as a universal (Messenger) to men, giving them glad tidings, and warning them (against sin), but most men understand not

that men don't understand his message (glad tidings & warnings) is not about having different language believing Allah to be the Wise, but it has other reasons that I avoid to explain as many scholars I've read their books about this verse have had criticized the Hadeeth I talked about.
In another Hadeeth referring to the saying of Allah that " أُوحِيَ إِلَيَّ هَذَا الْقُرْآنُ لِأُنْذِرَكُمْ بِهِ وَ مَنْ بَلَغَ", it is stated that the holy prophet PBUHH warns those with him and anyone whoever Quran reaches, and does this with their own language, maybe another saying of Allah being a proper witness to this Hadeeth when Allah says "وَ مَا أَرْسَلْنَا مِنْ رَسُولٍ إِلَّا بِلِسَانِ قَوْمِهِ" translated to "We sent not a messenger except (to teach) in the language of his (own) people" and the people of the holy prophet PBUHH are everyone up to Qiyamah, as he is the last messenger and universal (كَافَّةً لِلنَّاسِ).
Update @Afiq, this Hadeeth from Imam Javad PBUH is from بصائرالدرجات, the chapter gathering Ahadeeth about the holy prophet PBUHH writing and talking in any language, and note that there is a chapter collecting such Ahadeeth in an authentic Hadeeth book [sorry for not translating the Ahadeeth in this update, use google translator if you need translation, I'm short in time now]:

حدثنا احمد بن محمد عن ابى عبدالله البرقى عن جعفر بن محمد الصوفى قال:
سألت ابا جعفر محمد بن على الرضا(ع) وقلت له: یابن رسول الله، لم سمى
النبى الامى. قال: ما یقول الناس؟ قال: قلت له: جعلت فداک یزعمون انما
سمى النبى الامى لانه لم یکتب فقال: کذبوا علیهم لعنة الله انى یکون ذلک
والله تبارک وتعالى یقول فى محکم کتابه: «هو الذى بعث فى الامیین رسولا
منهم یتلو علیهم آیاته و یزکیهم ویعلمهم الکتاب والحکمة» فکیف کان یعلمهم
ما لا یحسن والله لقد کان رسول الله(ص) یقرأ ویکتب باثنین و سبعین
لسانا وانما سمى الامى لانه کان من اهل مکة ومکة من امهات القرى وذلک
قول الله تعالى فى کتابه: «لتنذر ام القرى ومن حولها»

in another Hadeeth from Imam Sadiq PBUH we read about the holy prophet PBUHH:

و یخاطب کل قوم بألسنتهم

or in another Hadeeth from Aby-Dhar:

عن ابى ذرالغفارى قال: والله الذى لا اله الا هو، ما مات ابوطالب حتى أسلم بلسان الحبشة وقال لرسول الله(ص): أتفقه الحبشة؟ قال: یا عم ان الله علمنى جمیع الکلام. قال: یا محمد! اسدان لمصافاقا لها لاها، یعنى أشهد مخلصاً لا اله الا الله. فبکى رسول الله(ص) وقال: ان الله اقرّ عینى
بأبى طالب

and there are many other Ahadeeth as well, and that's not strange if David and Salamon PBUT used to talk with birds and animals, and so did the holy prophet PBUHH and his households. Also many Ahadeeth are available on this issue ...

However, that Quran be very much alike to old Testament, what's wrong with that? A same God has sent several prophets:

قُلْ آمَنَّا بِاللَّهِ وَ مَا أُنْزِلَ عَلَيْنَا وَ مَا أُنْزِلَ عَلَيٰ إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَ إِسْمَاعِيلَ وَ إِسْحَاقَ وَ يَعْقُوبَ وَ الْأَسْبَاطِ وَ مَا أُوتِيَ مُوسَيٰ وَ عِيسَيٰ وَ النَّبِيُّونَ مِنْ رَبِّهِمْ لَا نُفَرِّقُ بَيْنَ أَحَدٍ مِنْهُمْ وَ نَحْنُ لَهُ مُسْلِمُونَ
Say, 'We have believed in Allah and in what was revealed to us and what was revealed to Abraham, Ishmael, Isaac, Jacob, and the Descendants, and in what was given to Moses and Jesus and to the prophets from their Lord. We make no distinction between any of them, and we are Muslims [submitting] to Him.'

Also there is a Hadeeth from Imam Ali PBUH saying, e.g. whoever recite the Chapter 87 (الأعلیٰ) of Quran, that would be like has recited Turah and the Abraham's book.

There's nothing wrong with that. But I want to know if there's archeologal, historical evidence for his knowledge of other languages.

@BastamTajik, sorry I didn't find any clue, but strengthened the reasoning from Quran and Hadeeth. Hope that will help

Where to find the hadith that he ﷺ knew 72 languages?

@Afiq, updated the answer, adding some Ahadeeth including the one you asked for.

Would you mind giving the name of the authentic book of hadith as well as the numbering?

@owari the last hadith doesn't actually prove that the Prophet could read and write. All it reads is that the Prophet spoke Abyssinian. And that itself is not necessarily proof that he knew 70 languages. Abyssinia and the Arab Peninsula are neighbouring lands. He also knew other local Arabic dialects, and would communicate with visitors from other parts of Arabia in their own dialects.

@owari Baraka bint Thaʿlaba was the woman who raised the Prophet and she was Abyssinian. It's easy to argue that he learned Abyssinian from her.

@owari the idea of 70 languages is based on the ethnological table in Genesis 10, which lists 70 grandsons of Noah, each of whom became the ancestor of a nation. The Talmud and Midrash also mention the concept of 70 languages in various passages. For example, the Talmud states that God spoke his word in 70 languages when he gave the Torah on Sinai, and that Moses translated the Torah into 70 languages before his death.

@owari but here's the problem, linguists estimate that around 31,000 languages have existed in human history, but only 6,500 are still spoken today. The Ethnologue guide lists 7,139 officially recognized languages in the world, but this number is declining.

@Afiq, already told the books name in the answer, that is "بصائر الدرجات" in short, and the part I talked about is Vol.2, Chapter 5, extract 4. The author has passed away in 290 Hijri (Lunar) and was a companion of Imam Askari PBUH. The part contains Ahadeeth saying the holy prophet PBUH used to talk in every lang

Not only abou the holy prophet, but even about some other prophets we are told they knew other languages as well, like Hadeeth saying all the prophets in person used to worship Allah in Arabic, or that Joseph PBUH knew a lot of languages, and that some prophets have talked with some animals, David and Salomon PBUY being the most famous ones, but also the Holy Prophet PBUHH. Talking with ants is so much different from 31000 languages that you talked about and they all had many things in common. The 72 languages in that Hadeeth might point to something different.

For example, maybe there is 72 main language from which several other languages being derived from it. Only a guess, I don't know much about these issues. But only one thing is important to mention, that there is a knowledge of names given to Adam PBUH, and that beyond that knowledge is the knowledge of Alphabets, each being a name of Allah. There are Ahadeeth describing about such issues, from which m=one may easily conclude knowing several languages is not a very odd thing if someone can see the meanings beyond the sentences, words and alphabets,

and even any sort of communications between animals, and even mountains, stones and water.

@owari I noticed that hadith. But it is linked back to Ja'far bin Muhammad which was born on 702 AD. Also being able to speak a language is different from reading and writing said language.

It is still skeptical. If we are to accept that the Prophet spoke many languages then it requires extraordinary evidence. Not that I'm arguing that its an impossibility. But we hardly have any testimony from earlier generations that the Prophet spoke anything alien to his contemporaries. Abyssinian, Hebrew or other semitic languages may be exceptions but only because he was in contact with people who spoke those languages which is not surprising.

One thing to know about the Sahaba is that they were very observant and articulate.

If the Prophet could speak all of the world's languages then where's the wisdom behind it if his first recipients were Arabs who didn't know or were less acquianted to languages not of their mother tongue? What's the use of such languages if he didn't even live long to spread his Message to other lands?

With a number SO GREAT, irrespective if it's 70 or 31,000, it requires hard evidence. The claim is that he could read and write but there's no physical evidence for this. We would expect the Prophet to have had his own written works for the convenience of all nations Arab and foreign. There is no Qur'an in a foreign tongue either. The evidence we have is that he had scribes who wrote the Qur'an and letters on his behalf. Another problem is that those scribes were Arabs and Arabic speaking Jewish converts; it is inconvenient to have them write languages that they were not akin to

There's also no eye-witness accounts, not even from the Umm ul Mu'mineen i.e. those who knew him better, that he ever wrote anything whether Arabic or foreign. This is further proof that he couldn't read and write. The ability to speak other languages, whether divinely inspired or not, as an alternative doesn't solve the problem either. Again he passed away before he could conquer other nations and his contemporaries were predominantly Arabs. Those who were multilingual at all were themselves rare and limited.

@Afiq, the first verse of Quran revealed was "بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ اقْرَأْ بِاسْمِ رَبِّكَ الَّذِي خَلَقَ" and in Ahadeeth it is stated that Gabriel PBUH said "read", the holy prophet PBUHH said I can't, and Gabriel repeated the same command for two or three times, then holy prophet PBUHH found out that he could read indeed. And about writing according to a Hadeeth about the last days of the holy prophet's life, PBUHH, he ordered to bring something so as he writes something that people will not dispute after him, but there happened what happened.

Some decades ago a pious man called کربلایی کاظم ساروقی who all of a sudden learned whole Quran, and although being illiterate, he could read Quran's script, that is only Quranic scripts and not any other text. He couldn't recognize a from b, but when was asked how he read Quran he answered back I see the light therein, and just know what is written there.

Even almost all of us have had such experiments, like when we confront a new issue not familiar with, but then we are inspired by the answer, and there are Ahadeeth saying the knowledge of the holy prophet's household PBUT was such, at least parts of the knowledge, through روح القدس or روح من امر ربّه, the doubt is mine.

@owari The answer is simply that Gabriel asked the Prophet ﷺ to recite (since Iqraa' could mean recite), and the Prophet ﷺ replied, "What shall I recite?" three times. During this, Gabriel was squeezing him. Some scholars said that Gabriel squeezed the Prophet ﷺ thrice to ensure that he wasn't dreaming and that this was a real experience. Some said it was done to empty/prepare/purify the receptacle of revelation.

One can easily understand those statements of the Prophet, which means that he had them written down. (Refer to Ibn Hajar Al Asqalani's Fathul Baari, Kitab: Al Jihad Wal Sayr, Bab: Salh Hudaybiyyah fil Hudaybiyyah, Hadith no. 3336)

As far as the Prophet's ﷺ final aiment is concerned, this wouldn't contradict my points as well as other narrations. This is easily harmonized by saying that the Prophet ﷺ could read and write later in life. How later? It's hard to say. But it's definitely not before 628 AD. The Treaty of Hudaibiyah was ratified during that year and the document itself was written by Ali ibn Abi Talib RA instead of the Prophet ﷺ

Despite this, there is no certainty regarding the extent to which the Prophet ﷺ was able to read and write during his last years.

@Afiq, thanks for I enjoyed your comments a lot :) Now what if we believe (according to many Ahadeeth) the hole prophet PBUHH had all the knowledge people had to that time, and have even at present, and will have ever after? Doesn't this include the writing/reading skills of every and any language?

@owari Your welcome. That belief is unorthodox. I'm familiar with many of the ahadith used in support of this and they are either misinterpreted, exaggerated or unreliable. Even the unreliable ones don't mean to convey that. Many scholars, especially in the subcontinent, have addressed this issue. I recommend visiting barelwism.wordpress.com and deoband.org

@Afiq, I should disagree on this, those many (though perhaps not all) Ahadeeth are neither misinterpreted, nor exagerated, as many scholars have defended them based on many Quranic verses and authentic other Ahadeeth (no place to discuss such a long story here), also many such Ahadeeth are themselves in the most authentic Hadeeth books, so are reliable indeed. This single point, will be a good answer to the main question of this topic as far as I can say, ...

... beside all the other evidences discussed in the answer above, and in comments that followed. Some issues are debatable though as you discussed around, but the main point still persists.

@owari yes they are misinterpreted as many scholars as well have responded to the idea. Those Qur'anic verses themselves are just as misinterpteted and exaggerated as they are. Such a belief is alien. None of the classical scholars ever endorsed it. I didn't deny the authenticiity of most of them at all. I just gave you two websites as a headstart to know the truth of the matter. Another site is islamqa.info. .

One thing to know is that quotes from some mystics and late scholars tend to be used to support this errant view. The mistakes coming from mystics and late scholars are not proof in Shari'ah. Nor do they make their mistaken beliefs any less grave.

I'm afraid this is not the place to discuss such issues. Debates are not welcomed here especially in the comments.

So far the sources you gave are from the books of the Shi'a. Unfortunately discussing sectarian differences is beyond my calibre. I can only speak for Sunni sources. From what I've learned, the alleged evidences from our sources are indeed mostly authentic but have been misread and misused

Another piece of evidence dismissing the belief that the Prophet ﷺ knew many languages are the letters he had sent to the kingdoms outside of Arabia. THAT WAS THE OPPORTUNITY to write in foreign languages. Instead the letters were written in pure Arabic. What's more is that we have those letters preserved. So it's not like the Prophet ﷺ didn't have the chance to put his alleged linguistic acumen to use. Conveniently those letters were written by a Sahabi and not the Prophet ﷺ.

I myself know a website by a shi'i brother that has evidence to the contrary. It's called shiareformist.wordpress.com. Hence this is not monolithic.

I've given you four websites. At the end of the day we will agree to disagree. Let's leave it at that and call it a day. Jazak Allahu Khayr.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Medi1Saif, thanks for not deleting the above comments, I guess therein might be some help related to the main question, and yes you are right, we will continue the discussion in chat, God Willing.
